# Record external audio simply in Clojure

Tags: audio, clojure

I feel like I must be missing something obvious here (I'm quite new to Clojure), but is there a simple way to record external audio in Clojure? I've looked into [Overtone](https://overtone.github.io/) and [Dynne](https://github.com/candera/dynne), but couldn't find a way to record *external* audio.

Something like:

```
(require 'supercoolaudiolib :as a)
(def soundcard "XYZ_soundcard")
(a/defsoundbuffer x)
(a/start-recording soundcard x)
;; Some time passes
(a/stop-recording x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid there is no Clojure library for recording audio files. Overtone and Dynne deal with generating or processing audio.

I think you will have to deal with [Java Sound API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html) and create Clojure bindings for it published as an open source library :).

Comment: Could you possibly provide a simple example of how to use it? (or do you know a project that already uses this in Clojure I can look at the source for?)

Comment: The link I have provided is a tutorial how to do it in Java. There are also [other examples](http://www.codejava.net/coding/capture-and-record-sound-into-wav-file-with-java-sound-api) on the web. You just need to translate it into Clojure, or have them implemented in Java and call them from Clojure.